# How can I connect to an MBean from another machine?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I don't understand how I can connect to a JMX/MBean exposed service from a different machine.

I wrote a simple Java application and I can call some of the public functions using JConsole, but only locally.

How can I set the hostname and protocol so that another machine can use it?
Is it something I can specify in the code or is it a JVM setting?

There are already similar question but nothing useful yet.

Thank you.

Comment: When running locally jconsole can use the attach api to talk to JMX without any setup.  When running remotely across a network this mechanism cannot be used, so it is necessary to tell JMX to use a TCP/IP network port.  This is described in the JMX documentation.

Comment: I found really hard to find examples of java clients that are able to connect remotely, even after reading the JMX documentation.